# Is it Possible to customize the About Tab for custom app in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am creating one custom application that is going to be available in the MS Teams. I have a requirement to capture data from the users in the About tab.

SO, Is it possible to customize the About Tab in Microsoft Teams for a custom application?

I will need to put the input box and form controls in that About tab.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely can't customize the -capabilities- of the About box - at best you could put in a link directing users where to go to complete the form that you've hosted elsewhere. Note that the About box does support markdown, so it might even be possible to embed the link as an actual hyperlink, but I've not tried that.

As an alternative, perhaps you could offer the needed functionality into the app itself. E.g. if you have a tab, put something in the footer for example.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot customize the About Tab for custom application, This is by design. You can customize the  App detail page as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/appsource/prepare/detail-page-checklist).